# CSS help - Can't place login form new slider

Tags: html, css

I'm teaching myself CSS and I'm a bit stuck with my page layout. I'm trying to get my login form to be right of my slider, but nothing I do works. Here's what my layout looks like right now...

[image: Current website layout]

Here is my CSS for the form:

```
.login-body { background-color: #f1f2f7 }
.form-signin {
    max-width: 330px;
    //margin: 50px auto 50px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-wrapper { //padding-bottom: 70px }
.login-bg {
   margin-top: -40px;
   margin-bottom: -50px;
   //background-color: #f1f2f7;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <!-- Sequence Modern Slider -->
    <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">

            <div class="da-slide">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
              <h2>
                <i>BUSINESS TOOLS</i>
                <br>
                <i>FOR YOUR</i>
                <br>
                <i>SUCCESS</i>
              </h2>
              <p>
                <i>Data visualized</i>
                <br />
                <i>to meet your needs!</i>
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg da-link">
                Read more
              </a>
              <div class="da-img">
                <img src="img/parallax-slider/images/graph.jpg" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


            <div class="da-slide">
            <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>
          <i>RESPONSIVE VIDEO</i>
            <br />
          <i>SUPPORT AND</i>
            <br />
          <i>MANY MORE</i>
        </h2>
        <p>
          <i>Lorem ipsum dolor amet</i>
            <br />
          <i>tempor incididunt ut</i>
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg da-link">
          Read more
        </a>
        <div class="da-img">
          <img src="img/parallax-slider/images/3.png" alt="image01" />
        </div>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="da-slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>
          <i>USING BEST WEB</i>
            </br>
          <i>SOLUTIONS WITH</i>
            </br>
          <i>HTML5/CSS3</i>
        </h2>
        <p>
          <i>Lorem ipsum dolor amet</i>
          <br />
          <i>tempor incididunt ut</i>
          <br />
          <i>veniam omnis </i>
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg da-link">
          Read more
        </a>
        <div class="da-img">
          <img src="img/parallax-slider/images/1.png" alt="image01" />
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      <!--<nav class="da-arrows">
        <span class="da-arrows-prev">
        </span>
        <span class="da-arrows-next">
        </span>
      </nav>-->
    </div>

    <!-- Login start -->
    <div class="login-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-wrapper">
            <form class="form-signin wow fadeInUp" action="index.html">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">sign in now</h2>
            <div class="login-wrap">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" autofocus>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"> Forgot Password?</a>

                    </span>
                </label>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                <p>or you can sign in via social network</p>
                <div class="login-social-link">
                    <a href="index.html" class="facebook">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                        Facebook
                    </a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="twitter">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                        Twitter
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="registration">
                    Don't have an account yet?
                    <a class="" href="registration.html">
                        Create an account
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>

              <!-- Modal -->
              <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Forgot Password ?</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                              <p>Enter your e-mail address below to reset your password.</p>
                              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix">

                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                              <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Submit</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- modal -->

          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Login end -->
```

Comment: why was this tagged as php and html with no code to support the question?

Comment: Float the second div left? Hard to say, missing code..

Comment: also, you realize that `//` in CSS are invalid comment characters and is breaking your CSS.

Comment: so, button set to ignore huh? well good luck with that.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I completely forgot! I just added it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to give the login form a `position: relative` tag and then move it to the top by giving it a negative `top:` property.
If the login form is displayed directly under the slider then you can give top the **negative value of the height** of the slider and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Design your two parts in **separate Div** tag.
Give **width in percentage** and set **float property to left**